# Ljava.lang.String in Map

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I'm puzzled...

I have this method witch can take parameters from the URL in a View:

```
    public static Map<String, String[]> getParameters() {
    final Set<Map.Entry<String,String[]>> entries = request().queryString().entrySet();
    Map <String, String[]> parameters = new HashMap <String, String[]>();

    for (Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry : entries) {
        final String key = entry.getKey();
        String[] value = entry.getValue();
        parameters.put(key, value);
    }

    System.out.println(parameters);
    return parameters;
}
```

When I print out parameters, this is what i typically get:

{yAxis=[Ljava.lang.String;@4ddf465,

I have tried to change value to

```
String value = Arrays.toString(entry.getValue());
```

Then it shows fine: `{yAxis=[Choose, Choose]`

But I can't go through the values because they are all strings and not a list.
I would like to have the values linked in a String[] with the keys so I could iterate trough it. I can't iterate when it's just a String. I'm sure this is a simple problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Please, help me...

Comment: Uhm, how is that complicated? `for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry: map.entrySet()) { for (String s: entry.getValue() { doSomething(); } }`

Comment: Don't bother clarifying your question with a comment. Edit your question so *it* is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the toString() for all arrays just defaults to the method provided by Object which is the print the internal description for the class and the "identity" hashCode.

If you have `String[]` in your directory structure, you have to do the toString yourself, the default won't do what you want/expect.  One way around this is to use a `List<String>` e.g. `ArrayList<String>` which will print as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

It's an array of Strings and not simply a String. You can iterate through the array and get (multiple) string values mapped to the key.

As mentioned in comment,

```
for (String value: entry.getValue())
{ 
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change `toString()` to reflect an own implementation of string representation, you have to write your own object containing the data and override `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from the default implementation of the toString method on an array of strings.  That is where the [Ljav.lang.String;@44df465 is coming from.

Create your own class to hold the values and implement the toString method to output the values the way you want.